# Can I use GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS to load only the pixels from an array of c structures

Tags: opengl, textures

I have an audio callback which is constantly writing an array of structures. The stuct has x,y,z members but also have another members after that.

Can I somehow transfer only the pixels of this array without re-arrangeing the array into new one lacking the additional members?

I see that PixelStore() can be set so TexImage2D() misses some bytes at the end of each row but is SKIP_PIXELS what i expect or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're reading from this array, you want UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS.

Pixel skip is defined in pixels, not bytes or components. If for example your XYZ data is 32 bit float, so one 'pixel' = 12 bytes, the skip factor can only be 1 = 12 bytes, 2 = 24 bytes, etc. So if your struct size isn't a nice multiple of the XYZ size, it won't work.

I suggest `glVertexAttribPointer` is a better match for what you want to do.